Google Sheets - How do I split a list of strings and find all the matches in another column with the strings
I have a column with of strings joined with , with an example being john,dora,sally and in two other columns I have individual names and salary with examples being john and 25 respectively.
How do I split the first string to find the matches in the name column and get the output as the sum of all the matches' salaries?

It may help to clarify your question if you included a sample table with a couple of rows of data? You can markdown tables as shown here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-add-tables-on-stack-overflow

Click Extensions / Apps Script, paste this code in, click save.
Spreadsheet must have colA is name, colB is salary, colC is your list of names, e.g. "john, sally".
Put your cursor in colD and type =SUMSALARIES( then click in cell to left (cell in colC) and press ENTER.

/**
 * @param {range}
 * @customfunction
 */
function SUMSALARIES(cell1) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const people = cell1.split(",");
  const salaryArray = getValuesFromColumnsAandB();

  return sumSalariesOf(people);

  function sumSalariesOf(arr) {
    let total = 0;
    try {
      arr.forEach(function(person){
        total = total + salaryOf(person);
      })
      return total;
    } catch {

    }
  }

  function findNameIndex(name) {
    return function(item) {
      return item[0] === name;
    };
  }

  function salaryOf(name){
    let i = salaryArray.findIndex(findNameIndex(name));
    if(i>-1){
      return salaryArray[i][2];
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  function getValuesFromColumnsAandB() {
    const dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    const values = dataRange.getValues();
    // Extract values from columns A and B
    const columnABValues = values.map(row => [row[0], row[2]]);
    return columnABValues;
  }
}


Assuming A2:A contains the names, B2:B contains the salaries and D2 contains the comma separated values, you can use:
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A=SPLIT(D2,","))*B2:B) 


You most likely need split the data, rearrange the data into a single column of values, and then match with VLOOKUP.

The SPLIT function can be used to breakup the data into separate columns based on a delimiter such as a comma.
The VLOOKUP function can be used to match data in a separate sorted table and return another column's matched value.
If you expect to have one name in the first set of data and many matching salary values for an individual name, then you will likely want to use a SUMIF function instead of VLOOKUP.

The following is an example of just using SPLIT and VLOOKUP without rearranging the data into a single column of values.


The first column shows a few rows of comma-delimited values.
The next set of columns are the output of using the SPLIT function.
The columns on the right are the values returned when using a VLOOKUP for the split columns.
The table in the bottom is a sample set of salary data used for the VLOOKUP.

